# MVVM ViewModel Naming

Tags: class, mvvm, viewmodel, naming

I have the views named as actions such as "SelectMethod". Wondering, if it makes sense to name the associated view model as "SelectMethodViewModel" or should it not use the action (i.e. Select) in the naming? I am thinking classes should be things so does the action not make sense or am I over thinking this? I know this is a simple question, but it has a trickle effect in the application.

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely go ahead and use the same name for your `View` and `ViewModel`. In fact I would take it one step further and add `View` to `SelectMethod`.

This basically ensures that we know the relationship and purpose of the two classes.

```
TestView
TestViewModel
```

Comment: Great and thanks! The counter is to leave it off due to Intellisense, but I like/prefer it for readability.

Answer (score 1):

`SelectMethod` is not a good name for a view. A method is not a class, but a view is a class and so a view is not a method. I would suggest:

```
SelectionView
SelectionViewModel
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Maybe, "MethodSelection". I like your point and also the clarity of "SelectMethod".   It would be great to get more feedback/opinions on the best overall approach and why.